# Homebrew on a network user environment

Tags: macos, network, mojave, homebrew, ssh

All the client machines are running Mojave. All the users are network users from a Windows AD. All macOS clients have a user folder as soon as a user logs into that client. My goal is to have a unique Homebrew installation with all the formulaes and Casks we need and the ability for me as an administrator to update them over an ssh connection.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What prevents you from using ssh to connect to each Mac and run `brew update; brew upgrade` to update "everything"?

Comment: Homebrew was designed really for single user use. and non admin users should and can be able to update their own setups. If you want admin control of setting up executables then Macports might be nearer what you need. You can just rsync - or uses some managment software to copy /opt/local around